# Excel macro runtime error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I can't find the root cause of my runtime error 424. I know it's to do with a missing object, but I'm not sure where or which object that would even be in this case. My assumption is has to do with ActiveSheet but I'm a bit lost.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Sheets.Add
```

**Error begins here**

```
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select, Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

**Error end here**

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Source Type")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1

End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Category")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2

End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Category").Orientation = _
    xlHidden

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Activity")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2

End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("USD Amount"), "Sum of USD Amount", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Quantity"), "Sum of Quantity", xlSum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely need to create pivot tables programatically so, to get an understanding of what's going on I created a little sub to step through:

> ```
> Sub CreatePivotOnNewSheet()
> Sheets.Add
> ActiveSheet.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
>     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Version:= _
>     xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
>     TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
> End Sub
> ```
>
> This compiles OK but throws an error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method. I searched the Object Browser for **PivotCaches** and found that it is a member of Workbook and PivotTable.  **It isn't a member of Worksheets!**  This makes sense when you consider that pivot tables on different sheets can use the same pivot cache.

So, change the code:

```
Sub CreatePivotOnNewSheet()
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
End Sub
```

and now we get a run-time error:

[image: no data for pivot table]

Which needs to be bigger to display the full reason (thanks Microsoft!) but I guess it goes on to say reference to a range that contains at least two rows and has no blank cells in its top row. While in break mode I went to the newly added sheet and created a little 2x2 data table. Back in the IDE, pressed F8 and it worked although the pivot table didn't have any rows/columns etc. defined. I haven't attempted to test your remaining code which seems to create the definitions - I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with recorded Macros, that there is no Objects defined at all.

I would suggest to replace all "Active" phrases with variables. Here is the start:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

Dim Caches As PivotCache


Set Caches = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ws2.Range("A1:C3"), Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion12)
```